# How to reference individual elements within a dialog/popup box, by their text label?

Tags: java, android, appium

Automated testing for Android app.  Using Android Studio, Appium, UiAutomater2 framework, and working in Java.

I have a dialog box that displays several options.  For example, "option 1", "option 2", etc.  I would like to be able to select and tap on a specific entry going by searching on the text "option 1" specifically.  I'm able to use Appium Inspector to get the xpath and the ID/Resource ID (in this case, `android:id/select_dialog_listview`) of the area that contains all of the option entries.

I would need to first iterate through the child elements of that element above right? For that matter, there doesn't seem to be a method to find an element by it's text label?

Comment: you need to create a method that accepts the index of the element, then take all the elements from the list, pass this index of the element to the method, and tap on the index of the element you need, you can also make an additional check and do it within the loop, which will make the method more universal if you need to select several options at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue when working with appium for windows, when we have elements with the same id.
In order to handle it I'm doing something like this:
Lets say I have 3 elements with the same id "buttonText" with the following text in each of them:
element_1: "Start"
element_2: "Pause"
element_3: "Close"
Lets say I want to click on the element that says "Pause" I will do something like this:
First I will get the list of all the elements with this id and save it to array list

```
ArrayList<WebElement> els= new ArrayList<>();
   ArrayList<WebElement> InstructionBtns = new ArrayList<>();
els = appium.findElementsByAccessibilityId("buttonText"));
```

So now we have a list with all the elements with this id.
Now we want to find one with the desired text "Pause" so we will check each element if he contains this text, if so we will return it\click on it.

```
 for (WebElement btn:els) {
            if(btn.getText().equals("Pause")) {
                btn.click();
            }
        }
```

Hope it helped.